# apache directory listing, download all

Tags: download

Is there any Windows tool or some way to download all the folders and files recursively from apache directory listing?

[sample folder](http://eamos.pf.jcu.cz/amos/kat_inf/externi/)

Thanks

Comment: Get something like DownThemAll for Firefox, which make slurping down a series of links a two keystroke affair (http://www.downthemall.net/).

Comment: DownThemAll doesn't have the ability to download these types of directory listings (particularly, recursively). At least, that's my experience as of 1 Oct 2012.

Comment: The `sample folder` link has permissions set up so you can't see it anymore.  Would it be possible to relax the security on that folder or post a new example?

Comment: The link is dead, try adding another one

Answer (score 129, accepted):

[wget for windows](http://users.ugent.be/%7Ebpuype/wget/) (or http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm)

Once installed it's as simple as: -

```
wget -m -np http://eamos.pf.jcu.cz/amos/kat_inf/externi/
```

The `-m` is an alias for `--mirror`. As a commenter noted, you probably want `-np` or `--no-parent` so that you don't go up in the directory structure. You might also want to add `--wait=5` so you don't thrash the web server, `--convert-links` if you want local links in the html file when it's done, and `--execute="robots = off"` if you're not getting all of the files (ignores robots.txt file). Altogether now:

```bash
wget --execute="robots = off" --mirror --convert-links --no-parent --wait=5 http://eamos.pf.jcu.cz/amos/kat_inf/externi/
```

Comment: If (in your example) you didn't want http://eamos.pf.jcu.cz/*, you would need "-np". I wish that I had know this earlier.

Comment: Is there a way to handle a http 401 authorization request?

Comment: I have created a batch file for that: https://gist.github.com/Bluscream/d29bdfe44f18b42831e5f978ebcd826e

Comment: Sadly this also downloads the index.html with all the sortings (https://i.imgur.com/LE6rvfp.png) is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: @Bluscream You could add `--reject=...` parameters

Comment: yo first link is dead