# copy files from remote url of same extension different names

Tags: php, copy

Hi I have successfully copied file from remote url to mine using ***copy***

```
if(!@copy('http://www.example.com/download/somedoc.pdf','./pdf/somedoc.pdf'))
{
$errors= error_get_last();
echo "COPY ERROR: ".$errors['type'];
echo "<br />\n".$errors['message'];
} else {
echo "File copied from remote!";
}
```

But I need to do it manually and one at a time. I did Google for * file name with same extension like somedoc.pdf. anotherdoc.pdf, next.pdf.

Is'nt there anyway to copy automatically to my local server from remote url that is newly uploaded

**Found My Ans:**

yeah got it.. used simplehtmldom.. The html code or www.example.com was

```
<a target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none" href="./images/download/somedoc.pdf">somedoc and somename</a>
```

and my code was

```
include('../simple_html_dom.php');

// get DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.example.com');

// find all link
foreach($html->find('a[target=_blank]') as $e) 
echo $e->href . '<br>';
```

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

now i will convert the output to variable and use the copy function

Thanks for the reponses guys..

Comment: potentially use something like ftp as the copy function has no way of knowing what files are available.

Comment: sorry to say.. but the www.example.com is remote url, so got no ftp access

Comment: if the site you are viewing shows directory listings, you could parse that page for file urls and then use copy.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5317668/4815044) this answer might help you if the remote server is apache.